# tcp keep alive basic query

Tags: sockets, tcp, keep-alive

I have a tcp socket for my app. TCP keep alive is enabled with a 10 seconds freq.

In addition, I also have msgs flowing between the app and the server every 1 sec to get status.

So, since there are msgs flowing anyway over the socket at a faster rate, there will be no keep alives flowing at all.

Now,consider this scenario: The remote server is down, so the periodic msg send (that happens every 1 sec) fails 3-5 times in a row. I dont think by enabling tcp keep alives, we can  detect that the socket is broken, can we?

Do we have to then build logic in our code to ensure that if this periodic msg fails a certain number of times in a row, the other end is to be assumed dead?

Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

In your application it makes no sense to enable keep alive.
Keep alive is for applications that have an open connection, and don't use it all the time, you are using it all the time so keep alive is not needed.
When you send something and the other end has crashed, TCP on the client will send all retransmissions with an increasing timeout. Finally if you have a blocking socket, you well get an error indication on the send operation where you know that you have to close the socket and retry a connection.
An error indication is where the return code of the socket operation is < 0.
I don't know the value of these timeouts by heart but it can go up to a minute or longer.
When the server is gracefully shutdown, meaning it will close its send of the socket, you will get that information by receiving 0 bytes on your receiving socket.

You might wanna check out my answer of yesterday as well :

[Reset TCP connection if server closes/crashes mid connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29018965/reset-tcp-connection-if-server-closes-crashes-mid-connection/29019212#29019212)

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to assume anything. The connection will break either because a send will time out or a keep alive will time out. Either way, the connection will break and you'll start getting errors on reads and writes.